# Return two lists to view

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, view, model

I'm trying to return two lists to my view, these lists help me fill some webgrid, I searched the web and I can not find a solution, I'm new to this

My Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<WebGrid> list = new List<WebGrid>();
        using (Web_INCAEntities dc = new Web_INCAEntities())
        {
            var v = (from a in dc.Cat_Proyecto
                     join b in dc.Cat_Pais on a.Id_Pais equals b.ID
                     join c in dc.Cat_estado on a.Id_Estado equals c.Id
                     select new WebGrid
                     {
                        ID = a.ID,
                        ID_kEY = a.ID_kEY,
                        Cliente = a.Cliente,
                        Tipo_servicio = a.Tipo_servicio,
                        Descripcion = a.Descripcion,
                        Contratista = a.Contratista,
                        INCA_PM = a.INCA_PM,
                        Importe_INCA = a.Importe_INCA,
                        Importe_Cliente =  a.Importe_Cliente,
                        calle = a.calle,
                        colonia = a.colonia,
                        Estado = c.Estado,
                        Pais = b.Pais
                     });
            list = v.ToList();
        }


        List<WebGrid> list_Usuario = new List<WebGrid>();
        using (Web_INCAEntities dc = new Web_INCAEntities())
        {
            var v = (from a in dc.Usuarios
                     select new WebGrid
                     {
                         Usuario = a.Usuario,
                         nombres = a.Nombres,
                         apellidos = a.Apellido_Paterno,
                         empresa = a.Area_Empresa,
                         estatus_Usuario = a.Estatus,
                         alcance = a.Id_Alcance
                     });
            list_Usuario = v.ToList();
        }

        return View("../Admin/Administrador", list, list_Usuario);
    }
```

in the return View tried to return to the view and my two lists to fill two web grid, only that I get an error, but I want to know how together these two lists so I can fill my grid

Comment: Look up the `ViewBag` object.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both the list are of same type i.e `List<WebGrid>`

you can use AddRange and concat both the list and pass to view

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<WebGrid> list = new List<WebGrid>();
        using (Web_INCAEntities dc = new Web_INCAEntities())
        {
            var v = (from a in dc.Cat_Proyecto
                     join b in dc.Cat_Pais on a.Id_Pais equals b.ID
                     join c in dc.Cat_estado on a.Id_Estado equals c.Id
                     select new WebGrid
                     {
                        ID = a.ID,
                        ID_kEY = a.ID_kEY,
                        Cliente = a.Cliente,
                        Tipo_servicio = a.Tipo_servicio,
                        Descripcion = a.Descripcion,
                        Contratista = a.Contratista,
                        INCA_PM = a.INCA_PM,
                        Importe_INCA = a.Importe_INCA,
                        Importe_Cliente =  a.Importe_Cliente,
                        calle = a.calle,
                        colonia = a.colonia,
                        Estado = c.Estado,
                        Pais = b.Pais
                     });
            list = v.ToList();
        }


        List<WebGrid> list_Usuario = new List<WebGrid>();
        using (Web_INCAEntities dc = new Web_INCAEntities())
        {
            var v = (from a in dc.Usuarios
                     select new WebGrid
                     {
                         Usuario = a.Usuario,
                         nombres = a.Nombres,
                         apellidos = a.Apellido_Paterno,
                         empresa = a.Area_Empresa,
                         estatus_Usuario = a.Estatus,
                         alcance = a.Id_Alcance
                     });
            list_Usuario = v.ToList();
        }
list.AddRange(list_Usuario);
        return View("../Admin/Administrador", list);
    }
```

or else you can create a class and use it

```
public class WebGridModel
{
   public List<WebGrid> List1{get;set;}

   public List<WebGrid> List2{get;set;}
}
```

and use it like this

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<WebGrid> list = new List<WebGrid>();
        using (Web_INCAEntities dc = new Web_INCAEntities())
        {
            var v = (from a in dc.Cat_Proyecto
                     join b in dc.Cat_Pais on a.Id_Pais equals b.ID
                     join c in dc.Cat_estado on a.Id_Estado equals c.Id
                     select new WebGrid
                     {
                        ID = a.ID,
                        ID_kEY = a.ID_kEY,
                        Cliente = a.Cliente,
                        Tipo_servicio = a.Tipo_servicio,
                        Descripcion = a.Descripcion,
                        Contratista = a.Contratista,
                        INCA_PM = a.INCA_PM,
                        Importe_INCA = a.Importe_INCA,
                        Importe_Cliente =  a.Importe_Cliente,
                        calle = a.calle,
                        colonia = a.colonia,
                        Estado = c.Estado,
                        Pais = b.Pais
                     });
            list = v.ToList();
        }


        List<WebGrid> list_Usuario = new List<WebGrid>();
        using (Web_INCAEntities dc = new Web_INCAEntities())
        {
            var v = (from a in dc.Usuarios
                     select new WebGrid
                     {
                         Usuario = a.Usuario,
                         nombres = a.Nombres,
                         apellidos = a.Apellido_Paterno,
                         empresa = a.Area_Empresa,
                         estatus_Usuario = a.Estatus,
                         alcance = a.Id_Alcance
                     });
            list_Usuario = v.ToList();
        }
        var returnObj = new WebGridModel
        {
           List1= list;
           List2=list_Usuario ;
        }
        return View("../Admin/Administrador", returnObj );
    }
```

Comment: Mark error in: List1 = list;
           List2 = list_User;